# Configure Excel to look by default in Formulas, Values and Comments

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, microsoft-excel-2007

I use comments allot in Excel and I need to search for a particular text that is in both values and comments. Is there a way to configure the Find and Replace in Excel to look by default in these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this:
For my workbook, go to VBA.
Under Microsoft Excel Objects > ThisWorkbook

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets(1).Cells.Find What:="", After:=ActiveCell, _
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So, whenever the workbook loads, it will run this code which basically do a dummy search and set the LookIn to Values (from Formula).  Excel tends to "remember" your last setting. Thus your future CTRL-F will use this setting.

I know you can put a dummy workbook which auto-loads each time Excel loads, but I prefer to set it for specific workbook instead. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Advanced Find & Replace for Microsoft Excel](http://www.office-addins.com/-excel-addins/advanced-excel-find-replace.html).

> Search and replace in all opened Excel
>   workbooks and worksheets. Simultaneous
>   search in values, formulas, hyperlinks
>   and comments.
>
> "Advanced Find & Replace for Microsoft
>   Excel" enhances Excel's built-in
>   `Find` and gives you:
>
> - Find and Replace in all opened Excel workbooks & worksheets -
>     Advanced Find & Replace for Excel
> - **Simultaneous search in values, formulas, hyperlinks and comments.**
> - Search in all opened or selected workbooks and worksheets.
> - All search results displayed in a tree-view.
> - Easy navigation in search results.
> - Replacing in all or selected found items.
> - Exporting found instances to a new workbook.
> - Show / hide the add-in easily (standard Ctrl+F shortcut).
> - Support of Microsoft Excel 2007.
>
> **Before the search starts, you define the search region by selecting
>   workbooks, worksheets, comments,
>   hyperlinks, formulas or/and values.**

[Download the 15-days fully-functional trial version (3 MB)](http://www.office-addins.com/files/index.html?addin=advanced-excel-find-replace&filenum=1&from=oa-bottom)

Comment: Thanks, but like 99.9% of superuser.com users I was hoping for a free solution.

Comment: You need to find/develop a macro for that. Good luck.